# Angular 12: ngModel variable not updating after async get result

Tags: angular, mean-stack, angular-ngmodel, angular12

I know this issue is very common, but I have done some research already and didn't find any solution for my case, I have tried some stuff like ngZone and setTimeout but won't work.

What I have is a component using ngModel that is updated via a get done by a service using a utility class, as you can check below:

`component`

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.init();
  }

  private async init() {
    this.initModel();
    this.initForm();
  }

  private async initModel() {
    await this.getId();
    this.getModel();
  }

  private async getId(): Promise<any> {
    return this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params) => {
      this._id = params.get('id'); 
    });
  }

  private async getModel() {
    console.log('getModel: '+this._id)
    if (this._id) {
      console.log('if')
      this.operationType = constants.COMPONENT.MAINTAIN.OPERATION_TYPE.PUT;
      
      (await this.session.apiManager.WorkerApi.getWorker(this._id)).subscribe(
        (response: any) => {
          this.worker = response
          console.log('await - ' + this.worker.name)
        }
      );
      
      console.log('after');
    }
    else 
      this.worker = new Worker("");
  }
```

my service class `Session` method

```
public async getWorker(id: string): Promise<Observable<Worker>> {
    return await this.api.getData(this.REQUEST_URL + "/" + id);
}
```

my utility `API` class method

```
public getData(request?: String): Observable<any> {
    const requestUrl = this.URL + request;
    
    return this.http.get(requestUrl);
}
```

What is "funny" is that I have the same code for another model in another component and it works perfectly, but here it won't update my input text (below) after my "get" callback.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" 
                required minlength="2" [(ngModel)]="this.worker.name">
```

Can you help me to understand what is wrong?

Thanks in advance!

## #Edit 1

I changed the `component` to use the `toPromise`and my `console.log` sequence is working now, although, the model is still not getting updated.

new `getModel()`

```
  private async getModel() {
    console.log('getModel: '+this._id)
    if (this._id) {
      console.log('if')
      this.operationType = constants.COMPONENT.MAINTAIN.OPERATION_TYPE.PUT;
      
      this.worker = (await (await this.session.apiManager.WorkerApi.getWorker(this._id)).toPromise());
      console.log('toPromise: '+this.worker.name);
      
      console.log('after');
    }
    else 
      this.worker = new Worker("");
  }
```

## #Edit 2

I just realized that I am having trouble to get the input value via my ts code as well, it just proves that the problem is with my two-way data bind (I guess). When I call the `this.worker.name` on my `onSubmit` event, the model is empty even though the input is filled.

It makes me wonder if the issue's title is wrong or not... Maybe "Two-way ngModel data binding not working" fits better...

Comment: Did you try this? `[(ngModel)]="worker.name"` I am pretty sure there is no need for using `this` on any template html

Comment: Did you happen to have added `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in the `@Component` directive ?

Comment: @Andres2142 I just did it, but still not working... =/

Comment: @RaphaëlBalet I tried this right now too, although the behavior is still the same, I noticed that the errors in the console due to the failure when trying to read the property name of the worker are now gone, this is interesting... all I need to do is add this in my `@Component`?

Comment: I see couple of issues with the code you have pasted. 1) `ngOnInit()` calling `init()` which is an async function. 2) `initModel()` is an async function but not awaited. 3) not sure why you have to await `getId()` which is a subscribe function. 4) setting `_id` inside subscribe of route.paramMap, but `_id` is used in `getModel()`. 5) `getModel()` not awaited. 6) not sure why you have to await a subscribe function in `getWorker()` 7) ngModel binding dont need `this` keyword. should be just `[(ngModel)]="worker.name"`

Comment: Hi @j4rey, thanks for the inputs, though my get is returning data, the issue is that my view is not getting updated after the callback. About the `this`on my `[(ngModel)]` I have already removed it, and still no changes

Comment: This or no this doesn't make any difference in the template. The suggestion from Raphael about the OnPush strategy wasn't a solution, but rather a suggested culprit to your problem. It isn't some magic fix, but an optimization that only works if you aren't subscribing to your Observables. In fact you shouldn't subscribe to them, but rather combine them with pipes or higher order ones.. And then use an async pipe on them in the template. That way you can even use the OnPush ChangeDetectionStrategy. If you make the effort of creating a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) I'll be happy to help.

Comment: As @H3AR7B3A7 explained, this wasn't a solution but if you did answered yes then I would have recommended you to remove it. You should definitively do a stackblitz, will surely help one of use finding the problem & the solution ;).
The `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` will make your component **Not being able to change himself anymore** _[Here](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy) for the reason why_ But basically, if this component, or any one of his parent (the one that declare him) have the `OnPush` then you shall not change the html from the component.

Comment: Even if this isn't good, could you try removing every `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` from your app ? (Just to see if this works again) so we could remove this potential problem

Comment: @RaphaëlBalet sorry for my misunderstanding! but thanks anyways, I did remove it already after the test... regarding the stackblitz, I'll try to do it so we can solve the issue, then I'll let you know! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out when creating a stackblitz as suggested by @H3AR7B3A7 and @Raphaël Balet. What was happening is that I had an extra HTML code using a `[formGroup]`:

```
<form novalidate #form="ngForm" [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form)">
```

It means, I was trying to use both two-way data binding with ngModel AND angular reactive forms, and somehow angular was getting lost on it and my model was not working. All I needed to do was remove the `[formGroup]="formGroup"` and it worked perfectly.

Also, a tip for the future viewers, the stackblitz helped me providing more precise error messages than my browser, so it helped me with other errors in my application such as null injections.